# MySQL query WHERE statement which is a query itself?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'll try to clearly explain my goal first:

First, I want to query one table in my database for a list of usernames.

Second, I want to take those usernames, and query another table in the database and return only the rows in which these usernames appear in the username field.

Finally, I want to take this output (in JSON array form right now), and return it to the requesting client.

My query looks like this right now:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tagusers WHERE username = 
    (SELECT userA FROM friendtable WHERE userB = '$username')");
```

This works when the WHERE statement yields 1 result. So if I only get one returned userA, it works fine. But if I get multiple, I get a bunch of errors.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];


$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("TagDB");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tagusers WHERE username = 
    (SELECT userA FROM friendtable WHERE userB = '$username')");

    }

while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $output[] = $e;
}

$output = json_encode($output);

print $output;
```

I get the following error on the query line:

*Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in C:\wamp\www\tag\appgetfriendinfo.php on line 21*

So all I really need to know is, how would I write that query in MySQL so that I get returned an array of rows?

Comment: Have you tried WHERE username IN (...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a subquery at all, you'll usually get better performance out of a join. Make sure you have indexes defined on tagusers.username, friendtable.userA and friendtable.userB

```
SELECT
  tagusers.*
FROM
  tagusers
INNER JOIN
  friendtable  
ON
  tagusers.username = friendtable.userA
AND
  friendtable.userB = '$username'
```

Comment: Didn't even think of an INNER JOIN. It will give better performance than my solution. +1 for you.

Comment: Randolph's suggestion worked, but I'm going to try this too for good measure. EDIT: Didn't see that Randolph approves of this. I'll make sure it works and give you the green check if so. Both you guys get a vote up though, thanks a ton! EDIT2: Yep this works! Thanks so much both you guys.

Comment: Yeah, it's late and I need to go to sleep. I've already thrown my name away on ServerFault tonight :-).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IN` keyword.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tagusers WHERE username IN 
    (SELECT userA FROM friendtable WHERE userB = '$username')");
```

Comment: Give @Dan's idea a try too. The INNER JOIN will be better performing (assuming your indexes are all good!).

Answer (score 1):

Use either the `IN` clause, or a JOIN like in this example:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT tu.* 
                    FROM TAGUSERS tu 
                    JOIN FRIENDTABLE ft ON ft.usera = tu.username
                   WHERE ft.userB = '%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));

$result = mysql_query($query);

$output = json_encode($result);
```